# Drools datetime parsing in decision table

Tags: drools

I am working on a project utilizing Drools decision tables. Inside of the decision tables are dates with timestamps as conditions. Previously the decision tables were included in the application itself and compiled at deploy.

We recently updated it to separate the files out into kjars for faster startup times among other things. When doing this a test that we had verifying our date parsing began to fail. After looking into it a bit more it looks like previously the date parsing was being done the `DateUtils` class, but with the files being compiled into kjars the date parsing is happening with the `EvaluationUtil` class which is stripping the time portion of the date off during parsing.

Is this an intended functionality or is there some piece that we might be missing to utilize dates with timestamps as conditions?

Comment: What version of Drools?

Comment: Originally it was using 7.54.0.Final but when updating to use the kjars it was bumped to 7.63.0.Final